# Show result of multiple keys and array column in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array like this:-

```
$str = array(
    array(
        'amount' => 1.87,
        'user' => 'hello',
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 0.9,
        'user' => 'test' ,
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 9,
        'user' => 'hello',
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 1.4,
        'user' => 'test1',
    )
);
```

Now I want to show the both the amounts in an html table which user 'hello' has. I tried the following for searching it :-

```
$ac = array_search("hello", $str);
echo $str["$ac"];
```

But it doesnt work. Is there anyway to show an result like this for user 'hello' :-

```
1.87
9
```

So that I can later show in html table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$users = array_column($str,'user'); // get all the user list from array
$search = "hello"; // user you want to search
foreach($users as $key=>$value){ // iterate over user array
  if($value == $search){ // compare user name with search value
    echo $str[$key]['amount'] .PHP_EOL; // if matched print the corresponding amount
  }
}
```

https://eval.in/1052935

Comment: Thnx it worked :D but any ideas how to get this on html table?

Comment: you can use same code in HTML TABLE. make sure file extension will be `.php` and add `tr` and `td` correspondingly.

Comment: <html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php $users = array_column($str,'user'); // get all the user list from array
$search = "man"; // user you want to search
foreach($users as $key=>$value){ // iterate over user array
  if($value == $search){ // compare user name with search value
    echo $str[$key]['amount'] ; // if matched print the corresponding amount
  }
} ?></td>

</table>
</body>
</html>          I tried this but doesnt show properly

Comment: @JeffB please ask a new question with code and HTML. and you will get answer by some-one

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($str as $new_str){
    if($new_str['user']=="hello"){
        echo $new_str['amount'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get this

```
$ac = array_column($record, ‘Hello’);
Print($ac);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = array(
 array(
'amount' => 1.87,
'user' => 'hello',
 ),
 array(
 'amount' => 0.9,
 'user' => 'test' ,
 ),
 array(
'amount' => 9,
'user' => 'hello',
 ),
 array(
 'amount' => 1.4,
 'user' => 'test1',
)
    );

$key = array_keys(array_column($str, 'user'), 'hello');
foreach($key as $value){
  echo $str[$value]["amount"]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for spending you'r time but it shows [0,2] which is wrong.

Comment: I used to get the array index of all that containing key user="hello". I have updated just check it